# Can I move app icons within the iPhone API?

Tags: iphone

I'm almost certain I already know the answer to this question but nonetheless:

Is it possible to move an app's icon to a particular page using the iPhone API, that is, without the user dragging the icon themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for Springboard that I'm aware of, so: no.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. What would be the purpose for such a behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That would surely break Apples strict Human Interface Guidelines.